# Particular solution to a $n$th order inhomogenous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the single $n$th order inhomogenous equation
>   $$u^{(n)}+a_1(t) u^{(n-1)}+ \cdots +a_n(t) u = f(t),$$
>   where $a_1(t), \dots , a_n(t)$ and $f(t)$ are continuous functions of $t$ for $a \leq t \leq b.$

(i). Show that this is equivalent to the first order system $x'=A(t)x+g(t).$

(ii). Show that a particular solution is 
$$u_p(t)=\int_{a}^{b} U_0(t,s)f(s)~ds,$$
where $U_0(t,s)$ is a Green's function.

I've done the first part, using the usual transformation
$$x_1=u, x_2=u', \dots , x_n=u^{(n-1)}.$$ But I don't know how to go by and prove the part (ii). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You can plug $u_p(t)$ into the original ODE (writing it as $Lu(t)=f(t)$) and use the fact that 
$$LU_0(t,s)=\delta(t-s),$$
where $\delta$ is the dirac delta function which satisfies
$$\int^b_a \delta(t-s)f(s)ds=f(t).$$

Plugging $u_p$ into the left hand side, we get
$$\int_a^b(U_0^{(n)}(t,s)+a_1(t)U_0^{(n-1)}(t,s)+\cdots+a_n(t)U_0(t,s))f(s)ds=\int_a^b\delta(t-s)f(s)ds.$$
This equals the right hand side.

Comment: What's $L$ here ? An operator ?

Comment: @Fib1123: Yes, it is the operator defining the original ODE.

Comment: Ok, by plugging in, it easily follows
$(u_{p})^{(n)}+a_1(t) (u_p)^{(n-1)}+ \cdots +a_n(t) u_p = f(t).$$
I don't see how to use the stated fact.

Comment: @Fib1123: Yes, that shows it is a particular solution.

Comment: @Fib1123: It does not directly follow. By plugging in, you only get $\int_a^b LU_0(t,s)f(s)ds$ on the left hand side. Then you have to use the two facts to show that it is equal to $f(t)$.

Comment: I think I just haven't quite got my head around some of this stuff yet so if you can please provide an answer.

Comment: @Fib1123: There is just one more step. I'll edit.